# Priority based queue in Anylogic

Tags: simulation, anylogic, agent-based-modeling

I am using a priority based queue to pick agents from a pallet rack. Priority of agents can be 0 or 1. If there are 10 agents in palletRack, I want to pick all the agents having priority=1 first. My problem in the current flowchart is: Agents with priority=0 are pickup up before agents with priority=1. May be because the agents enter & leave the Queue block one by one, multiple agents aren't present in the Queue block at the same time so that they can be sorted. How to resolve this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put a hold block between queueStorage2 and pickFromStorage1 and on the on enter action of queueStorage2, you check if all your agents are there, and if they are (with whatever condition you need to check to be sure everything is there) you unblock the hold with `hold.unblock();`